# How to send multiple commands to terminal(linux) from python?

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x

I want to send commands to run a python script to the Linux terminal. I have a list of python files which I want to run and I want to run them one after the other as we read the list sequentially. Once the first file is finished, it should send the second one to run and so on.

Comment: This sounds like a shell question, not a python question.

Comment: @Yuu While similar, that question is how to run scripts simultaneously, not sequentially.

Comment: Hey @KAMAL we would really appreciate if you could provide some [code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to better illustrate your problem and see your efforts so we can better understand what is hindering you to get the results you'd like and give you better advice/feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `check_call` function of the subprocess module which is a blocking call. when you iterate through the list one will run after another.

```
import subprocess

files = ['script1.py', 'script2.py']
for _file in files:
    call_output = subprocess.check_all(['python', _file])
```

Comment: Add this to your post, this is not an answer to your question.

Comment: Please don't use my response as an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 0):

You can run scripts sequentially using the following command:

`python script1.py && python script2.py && python script3.py`

`&&` runs the next script only if the previous has run successfully.

Comment: but for that, I need to write for every script.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through using the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call_call) module:

```
import subprocess
script_list = ['script1.py', 'script2.py']
for script in script_list:
    args = ['python', script]
    p = subprocess.check_call(args)
```